# Open a workbook (mode automatic) by VBA command without recalculating it

Tags: vba, excel

In my VBA `addin.xlam`, I use `workbooks.Open("C:\f.xlsm")` to open workbook `f.xlsm`. The workbook calculation mode of `f.xlsm` is `Automatic`, thus I realize that everything in `f.xlsm` is recalculated automatically, after calling `workbooks.Open("C:\f.xlsm")`. But this is not what I want.

Is it possible to open a workbook by VBA command without refreshing it, even though the mode of the workbook is `Automatic`?

**Edit 1:**

I tried the idea @Ripster suggested:

1) I created a class model `CExcelEvents` in `addin.xlam`:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

2) I linked `CExcelEvents` to the code in `addin.xlam` which opens `f.xlsm`:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents
Sub try()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
    workbooks.Open ("C:\f.xlsm")
End Sub
```

Then, what `try()` does turns out to be first opening `f.xlsm` (which triggers automatic recalculation), then changing its calculation mode to manual. The workbook has been already re-calculated before changing the mode --- it is too late! Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but you might be able to subscribe to the workbooks events and cancel the calculation. [This website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx) describes how to subscribe to the events.

Comment: well, I cannot change/add the VBA macro to `f.xlsm`, so I don't think it would work...

Comment: Just setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before opening won't work?

Comment: I tried that command in `addin.xlam`, but it returned an error, I think unlike an open workbook, `addin.xlam` doesn't know to which workbook the command is concerned...

Comment: I've used the method I linked above in an add-in to subscribe to the open event so that i could run some code every time a workbook was opened. I don't see why this would not work for your current situation. The method does not need to be added to f.xlsm, but to your xlam add-in file. It will give you an object that can subscribe to events of every workbook you open.

Comment: Post the code you have tried, and give the specific error message you receive.

Comment: @Risper, I just updated my OP...

Comment: would it work for you if `xlCalculationManual` is set `BeforeClose` as opposed to at the open?

Comment: @Jaycal I don't think that matches what I plan to do: `f.xlsm` is given to me as it is (automatic mode), I open it only for 1 time. Whether I close it, or its state after being closed does not have importance...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting XLCalculation to Manual immediately before you open the workbook:

```
Sub try()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    workbooks.Open ("C:\f.xlsm")
End Sub
```